# Bibtex style help - alphabetical sort

Tags: bibtex, sorting

I have found a Bibtex style that suits my requirements very well as it presents my sources exactly how I want.

I am using the `\nocite{*}` command to display all my bibliography sources from my `.bib` file. My issue is that the sources then appear in the order that they are in the Bib file rather than in alphabetical order by author surname.

Is there any way someone can tell me how to edit the bst file to make the references appear in alphabetical order rather than in the listed order?

I have been searching around for ages trying to sort this myself but to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! No need to add thanks in your question, we use upvoting to give credit to those who provide help

Comment: It is the bibliography style that specifies the sort order, regardless of whether you cite the references directly or use `\nocite`.  May be you are using a style like `unsrt`.  Please provide details, preferably by including a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I am using cj.bst. Filelink here: http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/bibliography/bibtex/contrib/misc/cj.bst.

Is there a way to edit the bst file then so that it does alphabetical sorting @AndrewSwann?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting of references is a job for the bibliography style file `.bst`.  The bibliography style you are using `cj.bst` is set-up to not sort the references, or rather to print them in the order they are cited.  `\nocite{*}` then gives the order they are listed in the `bib` file.

Reading the file `cj.bst` you can see that it has been generated by the `makebst` utility of [`custom-bib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib), plus a final bit of hand editing.  Fortunately, the `bst` file tells us that `custom-bib` was provided with the options

```
 %% merlin.mbs  (with options: `seq-no,nm-rev,ed-rev,jnrlst,nmlm,x10,x0,m1,dt-beg,
 yr-par,xmth,yrp-x,vol-bf,vnum-x,volp-com,numser,edpar,blk-tit,in-x,pp,ed,abr,xedn,jabr')
```

The first option `seq-no` means that references are to be listed in the order they are cited.  To effect sorting, we should reproduce this creation process without this first option, as sorting by author name is the default.  This may accomplished by creating the file `cjj.dbj`:

```
\input docstrip

\preamble
----------------------------------------
*** cj with sort ***

\endpreamble

\postamble
End of customized bst file
\endpostamble

\keepsilent

\askforoverwritefalse
\def\MBopts{\from{merlin.mbs}{%
nm-rev,ed-rev,jnrlst,nmlm,x10,x0,m1,dt-beg,yr-par,xmth,yrp-x,vol-bf,vnum-x,volp-com,numser,edpar,blk-tit,in-x,pp,ed,abr,xedn,jabr  }}
\generate{\file{cjj.bst}{\MBopts}}
\endbatchfile
```

and running `latex` on this file to produce `cjj.bst`.  Using this style as follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{cjj}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

with `bib.bib` containing

```
@Article{test,
  author =   {Author, First},
  title =    {Title},
  journal =  {Jour},
  year =     2000
}

@Article{type,
  author =   {Aardvark, New},
  title =    {Titling},
  journal =  {J},
  year =     2002
}
```

produces

[image: Sample output]

with the references sorted by author.

This may be good enough for your purposes.  As mentioned above, the file `cj.bst` contains a couple of edits by hand to change some fine details of the printing of certain references.  These are clearly flagged in that file, and it should not be too hard to implement those changes should you be so inclined.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew. That has fixed it perfectly. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Will using `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` or `\bibliographystyle{plain}` help?:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite*{}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}  %% or 
%\bibliographystyle{plain}    %% ???
\bibliography{myrefs}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have tried plain but it doesn't present the items in the format I need. I basically need Surname, Initial. (Year). "Item name". "Journal". "Page Number"